# Finding the price of an item years earlier from compound interest, simple interest, or APY

Tags: compound-interest, apy

Is there a way to use the compound interest formula, simple interest, or APY to find the price of something years earlier if the price of it was increasing by a certain percentage annually?

Comment: Yeah, you can solve for any one variable by re-arranging the formulas. A quick search turned up this site which seems to have a working calculator solving for present value:  https://keisan.casio.com/exec/system/1232691482  Note 'nominal' vs 'effective' rate options for APY vs APR.

Comment: @HartCO thank you for your assistance, the calculator helped but now I want to work the math on paper. what variable am I needing to re-arrange for compound interest to find this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The math is a straightforward rearrangement of the [time value of money](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_value_of_money#Present_value_of_a_future_sum) equation. Just treat the FV amount as the current amount and the PV as the past amount.

PV = FV/{(1+i)^n}

Comment: `i` here would be interest rate over 100, not just the number. For ex, 8% interest rate would mean i=0.08
It'd be good to add that clarification.